# FileSystemWatcher behaving inconsistently

Tags: c#, winforms, filesystemwatcher

I've set all the FSW properties in the designer (EnableRaisingEvents = true, filter = *.tif, IncludeSubdirectories = true, path = bla\bla\bla).

The application runs on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard machine and watches a local folder for created files. Instead of "C:\" i use the computers network name "GRAHAM".

The problem is that the FSW doesn't always fire when files are created/moved to the watched directory. It seems that *sometimes* it does, but most times it doesn't.

When debugging and watching that folder from my machine there is also some strange behaviour. If i remotely control the server machine and move files to the watched folder nothing happens. But if I move files into the watched folder from shared network folders the FSW fires, every time.

This makes it really hard for me to find the error/bug. Anyone got any ideas?

This is literally *all* of the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Ekonomikompetens_unikt_namn
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();

            try
            {
                log.Append("--------------------").AppendLine().Append(DateTime.Now).AppendLine().Append("--------------------").AppendLine();

                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);

                while (IsFileLocked(file))
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300);
                }
                string oFile = e.FullPath;
                string nFile = oFile.Insert(oFile.Length - 4, "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "").Replace(":", "")).Replace("\\XML Konvertering", "").Replace(@"\\GRAHAM\AnyDoc Invoices", @"\\FAKTURASERVER\AnyDoc");

                if (!Directory.Exists(nFile.Substring(0, nFile.LastIndexOf('\\'))))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(nFile.Substring(0, nFile.LastIndexOf('\\')));
                    File.Move(oFile, nFile);
                    Directory.Delete(oFile.Substring(0, oFile.LastIndexOf('\\')));
                }
                else
                {
                    File.Move(oFile, nFile);
                }

                log.Append("* Moved and stamped file: ").AppendLine().Append(oFile).Append(" to ").Append(nFile).AppendLine().Append("--------------------").AppendLine();

            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                log.AppendLine().Append("*** ERROR *** ").Append(x).AppendLine().AppendLine();
            }
            finally
            {
                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\tidslog\log.txt", true, Encoding.Default);
                //TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\PROJEKT\tidsstämplarn\log.txt", true, Encoding.Default);
                tw.Write(log);
                tw.Dispose();
            }
        }

        protected virtual bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
        {
            FileStream stream = null;
            try
            {
                stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                return true;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (stream != null)
                    stream.Close();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The try-catch-finally is probably not really well made, but I'm new to coding and not really sure how to "catch" stuff, the logger has never logged an error though. Since the FSW never fires there isn't a chance for an error to occur. I'm guessing.

Comment: Some comments based on @Anirudh 's answer: Since, your event handler code is busy executing, may be your files go unnoticed. What you should do is asAnirudh suggestion, use thread pool and next,  _fileWatcher.Created += (sender, e) => YourOwnHandler(e.FullPath);

Comment: For these "watch a folder for new files that may be locked and move them to somewhere else" tasks I always end up not using `FileSystemWatcher` and instead use a timer to scan the folder at regular intervals (say once per second), collecting file names and then trying to move them. The solution ends up being much simpler and more reliable when you avoid having to wrestle with the idiosyncrasies of `FileSystemWatcher`.

Comment: @ChristopherSirén: Read my exception series: http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/04/what-is-exceptions/. Maybe it can help you understand exceptions better.

Answer (score 3):

Subscribe to the [Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.error.aspx) event and check the error if any

---

In case there are large number of file being created or changed,do this

**1>** Increase [InternalBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize.aspx).

Doc say this:

> Increasing the size of the buffer can prevent missing file system
>   change events. However, increasing buffer size is expensive, because
>   it comes from non-paged memory that cannot be swapped out to disk, so
>   keep the buffer as small as possible. To avoid a buffer overflow, use
>   the NotifyFilter and IncludeSubdirectories properties to filter out
>   unwanted change notifications.

**2>** Also you are doing a lot of things in `fileSystemWatcher1_Created` which can cause the buffer to overflow causing it to miss some events...Use ThreadPool instead.

Comment: I'm curious: While the "created" Method has not completed, newly created files will not be detected? I though they'd be queued?

Comment: @Anirudh So, theoretically it also could happen that even if I put it to a thread right away, I still could miss a fill right? If you have like multiple clientes putting files at the same time to a location. I guess you'd have to setup multiple filewatchers and queue detected file operations (and filter doublicates or course)!?

Comment: @derape oops..I was wrong..I had just tested it and it does raise event even if you do Thread.Sleep for 1 min.But still the buffer could overflow and some events may be missed

Comment: @Anirudh thanks for the clarification, I guess the default buffer is sufficiant for most cases. Maybe I when I have some time left I will check how many file operations will cause the filewatcher to miss files...

Comment: I don't think the buffer size is an issue, there is only 1 file coming in at a time. And that file is a single image getting "stamped" with the current time and moved to another folder. When it works the operation takes <1 second. Could the buffer size still be an issue?

Comment: Also, when running the app from the server it never fires, shouldn't it just crash if buffer size was an issue? I get nothing (visible).

Comment: subscribe to the [error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.error.aspx) event and let us know the error if any

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate the error. Will post it as soon as I can. Right now it all works fine, even though I haven't changed much, well I signed the assembly but that shouldn't be a problem, should it?